# Attachment links in Body field in Notes Web UI

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I need to modify classical Notes Web UI application. In the UI, it shows mail data. If the data has attachments, they are shown as links in the body field.

I'd like to detect when a user clicks the links, and enable "next" button so that the user can move to the next screen. Is it possbile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and this has nothing to do with Domino specifically: put a div around your next button, that initially has the style `display: none` or give itself an ID and put the display: none directly in the properties box of the button on the html tab, fields ID and style.

Then write a little JavaScript that runs in the onLoad event, selects all a tags with attachments in it (they all have $FILE in the href) and add a function to the click- event to set the style of the button to `display: block` or something else.

You can prevent the default event (open the attachment) by using `preventDefault()`:

```javascript
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (el of list) {
    if (el.href.includes("$FILE")) {
        el.addEventListener("click", function(event){
            var yourNextDiv = document.getElementById("IDOfDivWithNextButton")
            yourNextDiv.style.display = "block"
            event.preventDefault()
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for great help! I'll try it. Thanks again!!

Comment: Feel free to upvote and finally accept the answer if it helped you, as upvotes + acceptance is the currency on this plattform.